# Start service on boot completed not working

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, boot

My broadcastreceiver doesnt work, i dont get the message in the log, can you please help me?
This is my broadcastreceiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public static SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("A intrat in BootReceiver"," ");
        if (!(prefs.getString(NotificareOptions.OptionsPos, "2")).equals("1"))
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceNotif.class));

    }

}
```

i got the permission, and i have the receiver declared in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

 <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"  
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="500" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Where is the problem? I also heard that `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` doesnt work on all android phones.

Comment: Is your app on SD card ?

Comment: I tried this on the emulator, and its not working, so i didn't made this step already.

Comment: Try it on your phone, and let us know if it works.

Comment: Also try putting the full package name on your receiver name

Comment: i added the full package name, and i tried on the device, not working

Comment: Have you got it working? im having same problem on same phone?

Comment: check this I already answared this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct.  This may be an issue with the emulator.  I too had problems with the BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast on the emulator.  It did not always fire when re-starting the emulator.  The following ADB command did the trick however:

```
adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell
# am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

This will cause the emulator to broadcast a BOOT_COMPLETED message, just as a real device does at startup.  This also has the advantage of being much faster than re-starting the emulator.

Comment: What happens when you issue the emulator command above?  Is your BroadcastReceiver code called?

Comment: yes, my broadcastreceiver code is called, but when restarting the phone it doesnt

Answer (score 1):

After i replaced `android:exported="true"` with `android:exported="false"` in my manifest receiver it started working. In many tutorials it doesn't say about it, but maybe this could help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I notice.  In your BootReceiver you specify:

`<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"`

This implies that the receiver is in the default package (e.g. in your manifest the value of `package`).  If this is not the case, or if you are unsure, you can specify the full package like this:

`<receiver android:name="com.mycompany.boot.BootReceiver"`

Also, it's possible that your log message is working but you cannot see it. You log as:

`Log.w("A intrat in BootReceiver"," ");`

So the tag is "A intrat in BootReceiver" and the message is empty.  Try putting in a message value that isn't empty.

Also, you can see that if Intent was fired or not if you have `adb logcat` running when the device reboots.

Comment: i have done what you told me and also tested on my phone, and its not working

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything directly wrong. But a couple of things to try:

1. Try naming your receiver with its full package.name.path.BootReceiver
2. Remove enabled, exported and priority from the receiver declaration

Comment: Is your BootReceiver class in a sub package? If not, try moving it to the root. Also, what phone are you testing this with?

Comment: i have it in the root, i test with a galaxy s2+

Answer (score 0):

Based on your indication that changing the value of `android:exported` resolved your issue, I think something else might have been in play -- rebuilding your code from scratch.

Conducting a 'Clean' in Eclipse (or the equivalent command in your development environment) could resolve this problem for others in the future.